# Compute gradients across two models

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, backpropagation

Let's assume that we are building a basic CNN that recognizes pictures of cats and dogs (binary classifier).

An example of such CNN can be as follows:

```py
model = Sequential([
  Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=...),
  Activation('relu'),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),

  Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=...),
  Activation('relu'),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)

  Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=...),
  Activation('relu'),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),

  Flatten(),
  Dense(64),
  Activation('relu'),
  Dropout(0.5),
  Dense(1),
  Activation('sigmoid')
])
```

Let's also assume that we want to have the model split into two parts, or two models, called `model_0` and `model_1`.

`model_0` will handle the input, and `model_1` will take `model_0` output and take it as an input.

For example, the previous model will become:

```py
model_0 = Sequential([
  Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=...),
  Activation('relu'),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),

  Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=...),
  Activation('relu'),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)

  Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=...),
  Activation('relu'),
  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)
])

model_1 = Sequential([
  Flatten(),
  Dense(64),
  Activation('relu'),
  Dropout(0.5),
  Dense(1),
  Activation('sigmoid')
])
```

How do I train the two models as if they were one single model? I have tried to manually set the gradients, but I don't understand how to pass the gradients from `model_1` to `model_0`:

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(train_generator):

        # model 0
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape_0:
            y_pred_0 = model_0(x_batch, training=True)

        # model 1
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape_1:
            y_pred_1 = model_1(y_pred_0, training=True)

            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_tensor, y_pred_1)

        grads_1 = tape_1.gradient(y_pred_1, model_1.trainable_weights)
        grads_0 = tape_0.gradient(y_pred_0, model_0.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads_1, model_1.trainable_weights))
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads_0, model_0.trainable_weights))
```

This method will of course not work, as I am basically just training two models separately and binding them up, which is not what I want to achieve.

This is a Google Colab notebook for a simpler version of this problem, using only two fully connected layers and two activation functions: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14Px1rJtiupnB6NwtvbgeVYw56N1xM6JU#scrollTo=PeqtJJWS3wyG

Please note that I am aware of `Sequential([model_0, model_1])`, but this is not what I want to achieve. I want to do the backpropagation step manually.

Also, I would like to keep using two separate tapes. The trick here is to use `grads_1` to calculate `grads_0`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking for help and understanding better the dynamics of *automatic differentiation* (or *autodiff*), I have managed to get a working, simple example of what I wanted to achieve. Even though this approach does not fully resolve the problem, it puts us in a step forward in understanding how to approach the problem at hand.

### Reference model

I have simplified the model into something much smaller:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Layer, Flatten, Conv2D
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(0)
# 3 batches, 10x10 images, 1 channel
x = tf.random.uniform((3, 10, 10, 1))
y = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform((3, 1)) > 0.5, tf.float32)

layer_0 = Sequential([Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=2, activation="relu")])
layer_1 = Sequential([Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=2, activation="relu")])
layer_2 = Sequential([Flatten(), Dense(1), Activation("sigmoid")])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
```

Which we split into three parts, `layer_0, layer_1, layer_2`. The vanilla approach is just putting everything together and calculate the gradients one by one (or in a single step):

```py
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    out_layer_0 = layer_0(x)
    out_layer_1 = layer_1(out_layer_0)
    out_layer_2 = layer_2(out_layer_1)
    loss = loss_fn(y, out_layer_2)
```

And the different gradients can be calculated just with simple calls to `tape.gradient`:

```py
ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights2 = tape.gradient(loss, layer_2.trainable_weights)
ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights1 = tape.gradient(loss, layer_1.trainable_weights)
ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights0 = tape.gradient(loss, layer_0.trainable_weights)

ref_conv_dLoss_dY = tape.gradient(loss, out_layer_2)
ref_conv_dLoss_dOut1 = tape.gradient(loss, out_layer_1)
ref_conv_dOut2_dOut1 = tape.gradient(out_layer_2, out_layer_1)
ref_conv_dLoss_dOut0 = tape.gradient(loss, out_layer_0)
ref_conv_dOut1_dOut0 = tape.gradient(out_layer_1, out_layer_0)
ref_conv_dOut0_dWeights0 = tape.gradient(out_layer_0, layer_0.trainable_weights)
ref_conv_dOut1_dWeights1 = tape.gradient(out_layer_1, layer_1.trainable_weights)
ref_conv_dOut2_dWeights2 = tape.gradient(out_layer_2, layer_2.trainable_weights)
```

We will use these values later to compare the correctness of our approach.

### Split model with manual autodiff

For splitting, we mean that every `layer_x` needs to have its own `GradientTape`, responsible for generating its own gradient:

```py
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_0:
    out_layer_0 = model.layers[0](x)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_1:
    tape_1.watch(out_layer_0)
    out_layer_1 = model.layers[1](out_layer_0)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_2:
    tape_2.watch(out_layer_1)
    out_flatten = model.layers[2](out_layer_1)
    out_layer_2 = model.layers[3](out_flatten)
    loss = loss_fn(y, out_layer_2)
```

Now, using simply `tape_n.gradient` for every step will not work. We are basically losing a lot of information that we can not recover afterwards.

Instead, we have to use [`tape.jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) and [`tape.batch_jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian), except for [image], as we only have one value as a source.

```py
dOut0_dWeights0 = tape_0.jacobian(out_layer_0, model.layers[0].trainable_weights)

dOut1_dOut0 = tape_1.batch_jacobian(out_layer_1, out_layer_0)
dOut1_dWeights1 = tape_1.jacobian(out_layer_1, model.layers[1].trainable_weights)

dOut2_dOut1 = tape_2.batch_jacobian(out_layer_2, out_layer_1)
dOut2_dWeights2 = tape_2.jacobian(out_layer_2, model.layers[3].trainable_weights)

dLoss_dOut2 = tape_2.gradient(loss, out_layer_2) # or dL/dY
```

We will use a couple of utility functions to adjust the result to what we want:

```py
def add_missing_axes(source_tensor, target_tensor):
    len_missing_axes = len(target_tensor.shape) - len(source_tensor.shape)
    # note: the number of tf.newaxis is determined by the number of axis missing to reach
    # the same dimension of the target tensor
    assert len_missing_axes >= 0

    # convenience renaming
    source_tensor_extended = source_tensor
    # add every missing axis
    for _ in range(len_missing_axes):
        source_tensor_extended = source_tensor_extended[..., tf.newaxis]

    return source_tensor_extended

def upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOutUpstream_dWeightsLocal, dLoss_dOutUpstream):
    dLoss_dOutUpstream_extended = add_missing_axes(dLoss_dOutUpstream, dOutUpstream_dWeightsLocal)
    # reduce over the first axes
    len_reduce = range(len(dLoss_dOutUpstream.shape))
    return tf.reduce_sum(dOutUpstream_dWeightsLocal * dLoss_dOutUpstream_extended, axis=len_reduce)

def upstream_gradient_loss_out(dOutUpstream_dOutLocal, dLoss_dOutUpstream):
    dLoss_dOutUpstream_extended = add_missing_axes(dLoss_dOutUpstream, dOutUpstream_dOutLocal)
    len_reduce = range(len(dLoss_dOutUpstream.shape))[1:]
    return tf.reduce_sum(dOutUpstream_dOutLocal * dLoss_dOutUpstream_extended, axis=len_reduce)
```

Finally, we can apply the chain rule:

```py
dOut2_dOut1 = tape_2.batch_jacobian(out_layer_2, out_layer_1)
dOut2_dWeights2 = tape_2.jacobian(out_layer_2, model.layers[3].trainable_weights)

dLoss_dOut2 = tape_2.gradient(loss, out_layer_2) # or dL/dY
dLoss_dWeights2 = upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOut2_dWeights2[0], dLoss_dOut2)
dLoss_dBias2 = upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOut2_dWeights2[1], dLoss_dOut2)

dLoss_dOut1 = upstream_gradient_loss_out(dOut2_dOut1, dLoss_dOut2)
dLoss_dWeights1 = upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOut1_dWeights1[0], dLoss_dOut1)
dLoss_dBias1 = upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOut1_dWeights1[1], dLoss_dOut1)

dLoss_dOut0 = upstream_gradient_loss_out(dOut1_dOut0, dLoss_dOut1)
dLoss_dWeights0 = upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOut0_dWeights0[0], dLoss_dOut0)
dLoss_dBias0 = upstream_gradient_loss_weights(dOut0_dWeights0[1], dLoss_dOut0)

print("dLoss_dWeights2 valid:", tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights2[0], dLoss_dWeights2).numpy())
print("dLoss_dBias2 valid:", tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights2[1], dLoss_dBias2).numpy())
print("dLoss_dWeights1 valid:", tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights1[0], dLoss_dWeights1).numpy())
print("dLoss_dBias1 valid:", tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights1[1], dLoss_dBias1).numpy())
print("dLoss_dWeights0 valid:", tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights0[0], dLoss_dWeights0).numpy())
print("dLoss_dBias0 valid:", tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(ref_conv_dLoss_dWeights0[1], dLoss_dBias0).numpy())
```

And the output will be:

```
dLoss_dWeights2 valid: True
dLoss_dBias2 valid: True
dLoss_dWeights1 valid: True
dLoss_dBias1 valid: True
dLoss_dWeights0 valid: True
dLoss_dBias0 valid: True
```

as all the values are close to each other. Mind that using the approach with Jacobians, we will have some degree of error/approximation, around `10^-7`, but I think this is good enough.

### Gotchas

For extremely or toy models, this is perfect and works well. However, in a real scenario, you would have big images with tons of dimensions. This is not ideal when dealing with Jacobians, which can quickly reach very high dimensionality. But this is an issue all of its own.

You can read more about the topic on the following resources:

- (EN) https://mblondel.org/teaching/autodiff-2020.pdf
- (EN) https://www.sscardapane.it/assets/files/nnds2021/Lecture_3_fully_connected.pdf
- (ITA) https://iaml.it/blog/differenziazione-automatica-parte-1

Answer (score 0):

i think  `model_final = Sequential([model_0,model_1])` would do the trick

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment :) I added a quick `EDIT 1`, as this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow - you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer as it would be nice to have some more detailed answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

`tf.GradientTape()` can take an argument `persistent` which control whether a persistent gradient tape is created.False by default, which means at most one call can be made to the gradient() method on this object.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Layer, Flatten
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(0)
# 5 batches, 2x2 images, 1 channel
x = tf.random.uniform((5, 2, 2, 1))

layer_0 = Sequential([Dense(2), Activation("relu")])
layer_1 = Sequential([Dense(2), Activation("relu")])
layer_2 = Sequential([Flatten(), Dense(1), Activation("sigmoid")])
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()

y = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]).astype('float32').reshape((-1, 1))

# print("x:", x)
print("x.shape:", x.shape)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape_0,tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_1,tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_2 :
    out_layer_0 = layer_0(x, training=True)
    out_layer_1 = layer_1(out_layer_0, training=True)
    out_layer_2 = layer_2(out_layer_1, training=True)
    loss = loss_fn(y, out_layer_2)

grads_0 = tape_0.gradient(loss, layer_0.trainable_weights)
grads_1 = tape_1.gradient(loss, layer_1.trainable_weights)
grads_2 = tape_2.gradient(loss, layer_2.trainable_weights)
```

can you check if this respond to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your comment :) this is nice, but here we are basically accessing the same tape. I would like to use two separate tapes, and somehow affect `grads_0` using `grads_1`. This is why I specify two tapes in the code.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I updated the response. i took the response from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan. hope this help.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. The gradient from `grads_0` does not take into consideration the gradient from `gradient_1`.

Comment: Thanks for the colab, it was very helpful to get a deeper understanding of the problem. here a link for the work, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rsOzA2loK_oOKUz7Ei1Qd3wN1pLZZpl5?usp=sharing